# spark UI and node configuration showing incorrect memory

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

spark UI is showing incorrect memory total as 371.GB

Machine type    vcpu    memory
n1-highmem-16   16      104   (master node)
n1-highmem-08   08      52    ( 2 worker node)

2 * 48 = 98 GB (leaving 4GB per Worker node for deamons & OS)

and Also if we look at the Node configuration. I could see 185GB alocated to each Node. I was expecting aroung 48 GB each node.

I am new to this forum. Let me know if I have to provide some more information.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqzKM.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VhYw.png)

also on Application page, I see 3.5 as percentage of cluster. It has to be around 90 percent.

I tried changing /etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml file  and tried changing below parameter

yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb 49152

yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores 8

Still it is showing incorrect memory configuration in spark UI.

these are my given basic dataproc cluster configuration

```
Machine type    vcpu    memory
n1-highmem-16   16      104   
Primary disk type pd-ssd
Primary disk size 1024GB
 
--worker nodes(two worker node)
n1-highmem-08   08      52 
Primary disk type pd-ssd
Primary disk size 1024GB
```

Comment: Could you provide the command you used to create the cluster? BTW, the UI you are showing is not Spark UI, but YARN UI.

Comment: How to login to spark UI in GCP dataproc cluster

Comment: It can be linked from the running container in YARN UI.